# Глюк с jQuery validate

Tags: jquery, валидация

Добрый день! Поставил на сайта скрипт валидации `jQuery Validation Plugin 1.11.1` про него вот тут можно почитать [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation). В общем поставил скрипт настроил одну форму - всё супер. Валидация срабатывает, `submitHandler` тоже (у меня на форме после успешной валидации, данные через `serialize()` считываются и через `ajax $.post()` данные отсылаются в скрипт). Затем я создал ещё одну форму, только добавил туда поле `textarea` и всё. Всё перестало работать, выдаёт вот такую ошибку TypeError: val is null
.../js/jquery.validate.js Строка: 914, в строке 914 вот такой код:

```
if ( val.param || val.depends ) {
            var keepRule = true;
            switch (typeof val.depends) {
            case "string":
                keepRule = !!$(val.depends, element.form).length;
                break;
            case "function":
                keepRule = val.depends.call(element, element);
                break;
            }
```

ругается на первую строчку из отрывка. Перепробовал всё, менял версию `jQuery`, отключал формы , чтобы на одной странице была только одна, в итоге выяснил что косяк из-за поля `textarea` , стоит его закомментить и всё работает. Причём ошибка возникает даже если я не ставлю Валидацию на него, а оно просто присутствует в форме. Кстати пробовал вставлять форму из примера (из документации) - тот же результат. Ничего подобного в нете не нашёл, может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой или просто есть светлые мысли - подскажите. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос решён, оказывается что jquery.validate конфликтует с jquery.tools , поочерёдно отключал библиотеки и нашёл в чём глюк.